# Display Friendly Name in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I'm adding items from a List to a CheckedListBox. I want that box to display the friendly name of the item to the user but have a "secret" actual value to use when the user selects it.

```
foreach (string s in x)
{
    checkedlistBox1.Items.Add(friendlyValue);
    //Now how do I get this to have the real value?
}
```

With drop down menus I can set the DisplayName and ValueName to something and use something like:

```
combobox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem { friendlyValue = x, realValue = y });
```

I can't seem to do this with a CheckedListBox.

Comment: Right WindowsForms sorry. I'm a Systems Engineer not so much a developer but I am making apps for active directory stuff. In this case my List<string> is populated by an active directory search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties on the `CheckedListBox`.

Those are functionally equivalent to the `DisplayName` and `ValueName` properties of the `ComboBox`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string FriendlyValue { get; set; }
    public string RealValue { get; set; }
}

public class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        var friendlyList
            = new List<string>();  // imagine it's populated with friendly values

        foreach (var fv in friendlyList)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(
                new MyClass { FriendlyValue = fv, RealValue = ??? });
        }

        checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "FriendlyValue";
        checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "RealValue";        
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be available as an option. If I type checkedListBox1.DisplayMember in VisualStudio, nothing comes up. It isn't in the list.  Also, I can't seem to add anything called "CheckedListBoxItem" to checkedListBox1.Items.Add. That isn't something that exists as a namespace. There's no such thing as CheckedListBoxItem as far as my copy of 2010 thinks.

Comment: @Sephethus For some reason microsoft hide those properties from intellisense. but when you set it will work :)

Comment: I tried setting the two properties without intellisense and it didn't give me an error, so that part works. What about adding these values to the list box? I tried using similar code to my comboboxitem example above except I used CheckedListBoxItem and it gives an error saying that doesn't exist in the namespace.

Comment: Really confused at this point. I set the properties there, but how do I add them to the checkedlistbox as separate values? Normally I go clb.Items.Add(x); if it is just a single value, and if it's two values I should be able to use clb.Items.Add(new CheckedListBoxItem{ FriendlyValue = x, RealValue = y});  Unfortunately CheckedListBoxItem does not exist, while ComboBoxItem and ListBoxItem do exist.

Comment: The list of values is coming from an active directory search. The actual list is populated with the real value, the friendly value is just a part of the full value. I'm removing the fqdn and backslashes to make it readable by the user.  Strange thing is when I try it the way you edited it actually ends up making it try to pass "MyClass" as part of the command in the event, rather than the RealValue.

Comment: I just figured it out! I realized I wasn't passing the real value in the event. I had to set MyClass mc = (MyClass)CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem; and then pass mc.RealValue. Thanks for the help!